# ASP.NET authentication cookie not deleting after Firefox is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, authentication, cookies

Im developing a small web aplication, used in a shared computer.

When the user closes the browser window, i want the session and the authentication to be deleted.

In the Login page i use something like this to authenticate the user:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket =
      new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,txtUser.Text,
                                    DateTime.Now,
                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                                    false,"");

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUser.Text, false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

As you can see, i have set the "isPersistent" variable to false.

This seems to work on Chrome (haven't tested on IE), however, when i run the app on Firefox, with multiple tabs activated, if i close the browser and open again, im still authenticated, and the cookie is still there!

Its really strange, beacause the cookie should be removed on closing... Is this a bug from Firefox, when you have multiple tabs opened? How can i fix this?

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the tips guys, but im sure im closing the browser, without any more Firefox related windows opened.

By reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies), it seems that this is the default browser behavior, choosed by the Firefox 3 designers...

Seems it stores on the disk cookies suposed to be stored on RAM, to recover the tabs when you open the browser again. So if you want to session to be deleted, you need to close all tabs, and then the browser...

I think this can cause some flaws regarding authentication security, for example, someone is using the application, finish the job and leaves, by closing the browser, and not the tabs. Since the computer is shared, right after another user opens the browser, and he will see all the tabs, with the previous session restored...

Comment: 10 years later it still seems to an issue, if I have at least a private tab open the cookies won't be deleted, I don't understand why they design it in that way.

Answer (score 4):

Are you closing the browser, or just the one tab? You need to close the whole browser. If you have multiple top-level browser windows open, all of them need to be closed. Also, any other windows that are part of the FireFox process need to be closed, too: Downloads, Live HTTP Headers, View Page Source, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on Mozilla or any other browsers,I would recommend you to use this code to delete the cookies :

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

For more information regarding to this topic : [How to: Delete a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx)

**Edit :**

If you want to delete cookies during page unload, you can use Javascript to accomplish that :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function deleteCookie()
   {
     var d = new Date();
     document.cookie = "v0=1;expires=" + d.toGMTString() + ";" + ";";
     alert(document.cookie);
   }

  </script>
</head>

<body onunload="deleteCookie()">
...

</body>
</html>
```

I think in your situation Javascript is the best solution.

Comment: And where do i put that code? Because i want to delete it when the user closes the window, and i dont find any handler for this.

Comment: @Tom S. : According to your question, I've changed my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this also delete the session cookie every time you click on a link to go to another page within the portal also?  Essentially forcing them to log in again and again for every page?  Tom only wants this to happen if they close the browser which I don't think can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cookies, use session to store the authenticated user, and ASP.NET will manage the session cookie for you, it works with FireFox and is more secure.

But if you want to continue with this authentication cookie place the code to remove it in Global.asax Session_Start event.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
}
```

Comment: Great ideia, removing it when the session start!

But why using session is better? And how do i store the authenticaded user in the session? 

Im using the authenticating system from ASP.NET, defining this tag in web.config: <authentication mode="Forms">  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>  </authentication>

Comment: This actually doesnt work, because the ASP.NET session doesnt end in Mozilla if you don't close the specific tab. If you close the window without closing the tab, the session is still activated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that if you set an expiration, you will get a persistent cookie, the following code works for me where I want the user to choose between a persistent or browser-session only cookie a la "remember me" checkbox when logging in:

```
 public void SetAuthenticationCookie(LoginView loginModel)
    {
      if (!loginModel.RememberMe)
      {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.Email, false);
        return;
      }
      const int timeout = 2880; // Timeout is in minutes, 525600 = 365 days; 1 day = 1440.
      var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(loginModel.Email, loginModel.RememberMe, timeout);
      //ticket.
      string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
      var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted)
        {
          Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout),
          HttpOnly = true
        };
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: make sure you haven't got the FireFox Downloads window still open...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this solution, might help some one else:

```
if (Request.Cookies["TownID"] != null)
{
       HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["TownID"];
       myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
       Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/p/1565112/3895452.aspx