# Firefox not deleting cookies

Tags: php, http, firefox, browser, cookies

> The time the cookie expires. This is a
>   Unix timestamp so is in number of
>   seconds since the epoch. In other
>   words, you'll most likely set this
>   with the time() function plus the
>   number of seconds before you want it
>   to expire. Or you might use mktime().
>   time()+60*60*24*30 will set the cookie
>   to expire in 30 days. **If set to 0,
>   or omitted, the cookie will expire at
>   the end of the session (when the
>   browser closes)**.

Taken from:- 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Can anyone explain why is FireFox not deleting cookies with an unspecified expiry time on exit?

I've tested in **Chrome, Opera and IE** they all delete those cookies at exit.

Is this a Firefox bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you saving your tabs session when exiting Firefox? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies) for more.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting a cookie expiration date in the past?

Comment: I tried your script ctest.php on my firefox 3.6 (osx) and it works as intended. After I set the cookie and open the page I see it when I close the browser and reopen it again it's gone. Tried it on safari same thing. Must be related to your FF.

Answer (score 0):

Is a residual process running? Some plugins for FF get stuck as a background process when the browser is closed, or the download manager may still be open etc.. is FF definitely terminated?

Also, this may result from a profile corruption, trial with a new profile (run FF with firefox.exe -ProfileManager)

Also, see here:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1465575

Notably regarding the corruption in the cookie manager:

> The cookies file may have become
>   corrupt. Since you are deleting all
>   cookies try this: 1) Shut down
>   Firefox. 2) Go to your profile. (
>   http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox
>   ) 3) Backup and rename the cookies.txt (if it
>   exists) and cookies.sqlite files to
>   a different name, i.e. old_xxxx

Comment: Nope Restarted my PC to clear the doubt, still cookies are there!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox appears to require that you include all parameters, or it will ignore the expiration and treat the cookie as a session cookie

```
<?php setcookie( "name", "value", "past_timestamp", "path", "domain" ); ?>
```

[more info here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#75343)