# C# definitely impossible to delete cookie with Firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, cookies

From a C# page, I can't delete a cookie on Firefox and Internet Explorer. I use the Expires changing method with works perfectely from on a Chrome browser...

I founs many way to delete cookies on the Internet, and in a last chance try, I execute them like this :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Response.Cookies["CDV_Id_User"].Value = "-1";
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        try
        {
            Request.Cookies["CDV_Id_User"].Value = "-1";
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Response.Cookies["CDV_Id_User"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Request.Cookies["CDV_Id_User"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        }
        catch { }

        Session["id_user"] = null;

        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);
    }
```

But even with execution of such many way to make the cookie CDV_Id_User expire, this NEVER works on Firefox... but only on Chrome...

HELP please ! :-)

Comment: Have you seen this?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205534/firefox-not-deleting-cookies?rq=1

Which refs this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies

Comment: I will check that point. However, the problem is that the code must work even if the tab enabled option is active ... ? Do you have a solution to be able to delete a cookie in these conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Firefox's save your tabs enabled?

[Firefox not deleting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205534/firefox-not-deleting-cookies?rq=1)

[Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies)

Try disabling saving of tabs and firefox should clear things out when closed etc.

Comment: That's right, when I first close the tab where my cookie was declared (and so deleted), that works. The problem is for my customers : they don't have   to know this "procedure"... is there a solution to delete cookie, even with this Firefox behaviour ? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. You'll just have to ignore cookies older than X on the server side.

Comment: The problem is that I use this method to save the identity of my users, when thay check the "remember me" checkbox. So, I need to have a "disconnect button" which delete the cookie by modifying the expiration date... if I ignore cookies older than X we don't have the possibility to disconnect before X time :(

Comment: So just append an element to the cookie : isDisconnected = true that gets set when they choose to disconnect.

Comment: The problem is, that the cookie is never updated : if I set the value to "-1" with : Response.Cookies["CDV_Id_User"].Value = "-1"; the value of the cookie remain as it is... actually, when the cookie is created, it's impossible to change the value, or change, the expiry date... it's uncomprehensible !