# Is there a reliable way to log a user out when the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, asp.net-membership

I am looking for a reliable way to log out a user or abandon their session when the browser is closed.  Is there a way to do this with tabbed browsers??  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Use session-only cookies, which only persist the length of the browsing session (i.e. until the user closes the browser).

Comment: For that checkout my answer on it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73904773/14870617

Comment: Checkout here maybe it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76152055/995853

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do this *immediately* when the client closes the browser. There's the `beforeunload` event, but even then, when you fire an ajax request during this event, it's not guaranteed to ever reach the server. Still then, you've a problem with multiple browser tabs.

Most reliable way is to have a relatively short session timeout in the server side (e.g. 1 minute) and introduce an ajaxbased heartbeat on the client side (e.g. every 30 seconds) to keep the session alive.

There may be better ways depending on the sole functional requirement for which you thought that this is the solution. For example, if your *actual* intent is to restrict all logins to 1 per registered user, then you'd better collect all logins and the associated sessions and then compare this on each login and invalidate the earlier session if any present. This way it'll work as well on clients with JS disabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using cookies to preserve your users' login information, it *should* log them out when they close the browser, because any session cookies should be killed when the browser closes.

Obviously this isn't always the case ([see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies) of Firefox preserving login information after logging out) because "session restore" features we now blur the line between what is considered a "single browser session". (Personally, I think this should be classified as a bug, but that is only my opinion).

There are two possible techniques. The first would be (as yojimbo87 mentions before me) to use web sockets to keep a connection between client and server, and when the socket closes, kill the session. The issue here is that web sockets support is limited, and certainly not possible on anything other than bleeding edge browsers (FF4, Chrome, IE9, etc).

An alternative could be to use AJAX to constantly poll the server to tell it that the page is still being viewed, so if, for example, you send a keep-alive request via AJAX every 30 seconds, you'd store the timestamp of the request in the session. If the user then comes back to the page and the time difference between the current request and the last request is more than say... 45 seconds (accounting for latency), you'd know that the user closed their browser and need to log in again.

In both of these situations, there is however a fatal flaw, and that is that they rely on JavaScript. If the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, you'd end up ruining the user experience with constant login prompts, which is obviously a bad idea.

In my opinion, I think its reasonable to simply rely on session cookies being deleted by the browser when the user closes the browser window, because that is what they are supposed to do. You as a developer can't be blamed when the client browser performs undesirable behaviour, since its entirely out of your hands, and there's no functional workaround.

Answer (score 1):

A feasible technique would be to use AJAX to send keep-alive requests to your servers quite often — e.g. every one minute. Then you could abandon a session as soon as a keep-alive (or a few in sequence) is not received as expected.

Otherwise, there's no reliable way to achieve that. Since there's not a persistent connection between the browser and the server you can't detect situations that are out-of-control of any JavaScript code you might have running in the browser. For example, when there's a network failure you might want to close the session as well even though the browser's window is still opened. Hence, to make the system robust enough, you should detect network outages as a “side-effect” of the keep-alive mechanism from the browser (e.g. like Gmail does it).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using WebSockets or some kind of long polling for each tab which tracks the connection with client in "real time", you will probably have to wait until the session is timed out on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a combination of Jquery,Ajax and PHP
The Jquery

```
  function updatestatusOFF(){
        // Assuming we have #shoutbox
        $('#connection').load('connection.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>&offline=true');

    }
```

The before unload script

```
<script>window.onbeforeunload = function() { return updatestatusOFF(); }</script>
```

and the php you would have to write yourself which i'm more then certain you can do.
it isn't the most reliable but it's the easiest way to implement that. if you want real time reporting .. look into comet