# Why is the session not expiring on browser close when session.cookie_lifetime=0?

Tags: apache, session, php

I set up a test version of a PHP coded website which uses sessions to handle user logins. On the test server, the session would expire on browser close, since copying everything to the "clean" live server, the session stays in place on browser close and the user is still logged in even the next day after full system reboot.

In php.ini

```
; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
```

Which implies that it should expire on browser restart.

I thought maybe it was being overridden somewhere, but if I print_r the session_get_cookie_params in PHP I get

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 0
    [path] => /
    [domain] => 
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 
)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: did you try it on other browsers? what browser are you using? The expiry value may be sent to the browser, but the browser may refuses to remove cookie on close. Check your browser settings as well and test on other browsers.

Comment: It is the same in Firefox and IE. Surely if it was a browser issue, the same would happen on the test server as the live. The behaviour doesn't happen on other websites (that I have noticed anyway)

Comment: Furthermore, it has been noticed by the client who the website was built for and he doesn't want it to happen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to add this as a comment on Alexander's excellent answer, but its going to get a bit verbose.

How long the cookie is retained on the browser and how long the session data is retained by the server *in the absence of a request* are 2 seperate and independent things. There is no way to avoid this due to the stateless nature of HTTP - although there are some things you can do to mitigate what you perceive as a security flaw.

For the browser to access the same session after being closed down and some delay it requires that both the session cookie be retained by the browser (which Alexander has already explained) *and* for the server to have retained the session data.

The behaviour you describe may be much more pronounced on systems handling a low volume of requests and where the session handler does not verify the TTL of the sesion data (I'm not sure if the default handlers do, or if they just assume that any undeleted session data is considered current).

You've not provided any details of how the 2 servers are configured, notably the session.gc_maxlifetime.

If the session.gc_maxlifetime has expired between requests but the session data is still accessible this implies that the session handler merely considers this as the time at which the session is considered eligible for garbage collection (which, semantically, is what the configuration option is for). However there is a strong case for treating this value as a TTL. To address this you could either force the garbage collection to run more frequently and delete the session data, or use a session handler which ignores session data older than the specified limit.

That you see a difference between the 2 systems may be due to differing values for session.gc_maxlifetime or differences in the frequency of garbage collection or even different session handlers.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using google chrome

if you set "continue where I left off", chrome will restore your browsing data and session cookies.

even Facebook login (without "remember me") session is retained.

for more info

[google chrome setting](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95421&p=settings_reopen_pages)

Answer (score 5):

Issue is here that a Firefox has a feature called "Restore last session". If someone uses saving tabs on close then it's the same. When browser restores the last session then all session cookies will be restored too :)

So your session cookie can live forever. You can read more at [Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies)

Comment: That doesn't explain why it only shows this behaviour on the live server and not the test server, or why IE shows the same behaviour. Also, when closing FF I am not saving tabs, nor am I restoring the last session.

Comment: Useful to know nonetheless, thanks. Seems a bit of a security risk in FF tbh.

Comment: Better solution for authentication is to use cookie with fixed lifetime and "touch" it on each request.

Comment: Would that not have the same problem in FF? Also, if I set it to, say 10 minutes, if the user closed their browser and someone else reopened it within the expiry time then they would still be logged in.