# How to start a new session (PHP, WAMP)?

Tags: php, firefox, session, wamp

All,

Probably a stupid question, but I'm developing a small site using WAMP (and Firefox to display the HTML produced), and I can't find a way to start my site with a new session.  The session persists from one window to the next, with all the user data in session, page count, etc.

How can I start a new session?

Thanks,

JDelage

EDIT:  Related thread of interest to others: [Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Browser based options

#### Start a new browser session

If you can use Chrome then you can use the `File -> New Incognito Window` option.

In Firefox it is `Tools -> Start Private Browsing`.

These will start clean sessions in your browsers.

#### Delete the session cookie

You can delete the session cooking using the cookie management screen of your browser.

### From PHP

You can create a simple script that destroys your session when it is called. For example you can have `logout.php`:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

The manual page is over at [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: Thanks.  I added a link to `session_destroy()` in my dvp code.  It's easier than to toggle endlessly the `private browsing` setting.

Answer (score 3):

A session is a combination of a client-side token (stored in Firefox) and PHP remembering some server-side session information for that token.

If you want to destory the session client-side, you should clear your cache (or start a new private window). If you want to destroy the session information server-side, you should call

```
session_destroy();
```

See here for a good tutorial in PHP: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php