# Opera does not delete session cookie when browser close

Tags: session, cookies, opera

I perform following javascript code in Opera javascript console
`document.cookie='test=abc'`
then I close all tabs one by one and then I close the browser.

After that when I open browser again cookie value `test=abc` is still in `document.cookie` variable.

I tried to reseach the problem and found this on official opera website http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.50/en/cookies.html:

> If no expiration date is assigned to it, a cookie expires at the end of the session, when you exit the browser. A cookie that expires at end of session is called a session cookie.

It means that Opera should follow standart behavior with session cookies, but it doesn't.

Also I found this [Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies):

> Firefox has a feature where you close Firefox and it offers to save all your tabs, and then you restore the browser and those tabs come back. That's called session restore. What I didn't realize is that it'll also restore all the session cookies for those pages too! It treats it like you had never closed the browser.

So, just in case, before closing the browser (Opera in my case) I closed all tabs one by one. But it didn't help too. Session cookie wasn't deleted.

Opera version: 17.0.1241.53;
Operation system: Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: SO is about code... what you describe sounds like it could be a bug.. which is best handled by Opera and not SO...

Comment: Looks like a valid question to me, even though the answer would be "is a bug". Good to know, if you're having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works is the manual block list, the manual clear on exit doesnt work either. Ofc the block all works, but that also shuts down the internet. You can also use extensions like privacy badger to control suspect cookies, but then again how secure are the extensions? Dont get me started on that. I am not paranoid, you however should be..