# How to keep cookie stored after closing firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

Why cookies are deleted after closing firefox? I want to keep cookies after closing firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox session cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox options go to Privacy tab and set Firefox will field in History group to "Remember history"

Comment: I have already set it to "Remember history" still it deletes cookies after closing it

Comment: In custom settings for this field you have more detailed options, try to test it

Comment: Also update your Firefox to the latest version because of https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1001421

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/954358)

> To summarize:
>
> In case you are using "Clear history when Firefox closes":
>
> ```
> do not clear Cookies
> do not clear Site Preferences
> ```
>
> Clearing cookies will remove all specified (selected) cookies
>   including cookies that have an allow exception.
>
> ```
> Tools > Options > Privacy: History: [X] Clear history when Firefox closes > Settings
> https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Clear+Recent+History
> ```
>
> Note that clearing "Site Preferences" clears all exceptions for
>   cookies, images, pop-up windows, software installation, and passwords.
>
> Let all cookies expire when you close Firefox.
>
> ```
> Tools > Options > Privacy > Cookies: "Keep until": "I close Firefox"
> ```
>
> Make an Allow exception for the ones that you want to keep.
>
> ```
> Tools > Options > Privacy > Cookies: "Exceptions"
> ```