# Why does PHPSESSID not exists in cookies.sqlite in Firefox?

Tags: php, sqlite, session, cookies

I'm using Firefox and I'm trying to understand sessions and cookies.

In Firefox cookies are stored in a `cookies.sqlite` file.

Sessions are identified by a session name. The default session name is `PHPSESSID`, which is actually a cookie. When I inspect the Cookies inspector tab at the Network tab then I can see the `PHPSESSID`. Please see below.

[image]

I assumed that there should exists a `PHPSESSID` cookie in `cookies.sqlite`. So, I opened `cookies.sqlite` in the `DB Browser for Sqlite` program. I'm sure I opened the right coookies.sqlite because I went to `about:support` to check the profile folder.

My assumptions where not true, the `PHPSESSID` cookie doesn't exists in `cookies.sqlite`. Please have a look below (I censored the hostname).

[image]

My question is, why does `PHPSESSID` not exists in the `cookies.sqlite`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35312/firefox-hidden-cookies-not-in-cookies-sql relevant?

Comment: @Federkun It's definitely an useful link. However, it doesn't answer my question because when I close / re-open Firefox the `PHPSESSID` is still not there.

Comment: Interesting link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPSESSID is a [session cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie). It should not persist when you close your browser so it does not get written to disk.

It is possible to [override this behaviour](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session#w_privacy-issues) (note the caveats) however I wouldn't surprised if the browser used its page state storage substrate for the session cookie rather than the normal cookie file.